# Form validation in structr

Tags: structr

How do I validate a form in structr?

When I add the value "create:MyType" to the Action attribute in the "edit mode binding" tab for my submit button, the HTML 5 form validation stops working.

I've verified that removing the Action allows the HTML 5 validation to process normally.

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, we've not been watching SO for Structr-related questions for a while.

What do you mean by "HTML 5 form validation"? Did you add it yourself?

Comment: Hi Axel -
You can add attributes like "required" to an input element, and an HTML5 capable browser will validate it on submit.
Example - http://www.wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html

Comment: Maybe it's related to the jQuery validation plugin structr-app.js uses. Will forward it to the dev team to have a look... Thanks for reporting.

Answer (score 1):

When adding an action attribute to a button (in the Edit Mode Binding), Structr automatically binds an 'onclick' event to it which submits the form, preventing the browser doing the validation based on the HTML5 attributes.

We're currently experimenting with different forms of client-side validation (jQuery validation plugin etc.) in the latest SNAPSHOT builds.

Ideally, the the server-side validation rules would be applicable for client-based validation. Difficult to resolve, and HTML5-based validation is even harder because not all browsers support it.

Comment: Thanks Axel.
What is the current best practice for form validation?
Would it be a custom JavaScript function?

Comment: If it's only for the 'required' attribute, try adding the jquery validation plugin to the page (or page template). This should add validation for mandatory fields (not-null flag set) automatically, and should be compatible with the Structr action binding.